# How to fetch specific field from mongo collection using morphia, if that field is removed from mapped POJO class?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Lets say class "A" as follows:

```
    Class A{
         String fieldOne;
         String fieldTwo;}
```

and collection "collactionA" as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f6b2f9f97864348632356d4"),
"fieldOne" : "one",
"fieldTwo" : "two" }
```

Now i delete field "fieldOne" from class A but as it is present in collection, and want to fetch value of this removed field "fieldOne".

```
dataStore.createQuery(A.class)
```

using above method only gives only field which is present in new definition of Class A(remaining "fieldTwo")
How can i fetch that removed field("fieldOne")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to query the collection directly using the driver so that you can get the documents back in a `Document` rather than an `A`.  Morphia will map all the fields in the document to any mapped fields in your entity but it will silently skip over any unmapped keys in the fetched documents.  So you'll need to get the "raw" `Documents` back from the database to fetch those values.

I haven't tried this, personally, but it has a decent chance of working:

`var query = datastore.find("collectionA", Document.class);`

That should fetch the documents from the collection but stop at mapping them only to `Document` instead of trying to hydrate entities to hold the data.